# Pine Script: RSI signal Multi-timeframe

Tags: pine-script

I´m starting with the pine script and I would like to know how to create a buy/sell signal with a multi-time frame. I want to buy when rsi 5 minutes is above 80 and rsi 1 minute is also above 80, same for sell signal below 20.

I´ve tried different lines of code (also security function)  and read forums but I don´t know to do it.

```
//@version=4
strategy("how to")

rsi = rsi(close, 14)

long = rsi_5m > 80 and rsi_1m > 80
short = rsi_5m < 80 and rsi_1m < 80

start = timestamp(2023,4,1,0,0)
end = timestamp (2023,4,30,0,0)

if time >= start and time <= end
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 1.0, when = long)
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, 1.0, when = short)

   
plot(rsi, title="1", color=#2600ff, linewidth = 3)

strategy.exit("long", from_entry ="long", loss=30)
strategy.exit("short", from_entry = "short", loss=30)
```

Edit:

Ok, this is the new code but I keep getting error, this time: "error at 8:10 Could not find function or function reference 'rsi'"

```
//@version=5
strategy("RSI Strategy", overlay=true)

// RSI conditions
rsi_5m = rsi(close, 14)
rsi_1m = security(syminfo.tickerid, "1", rsi(close, 14))

// Buy condition
buy_signal = rsi_5m > 80 and rsi_1m > 80
// Sell condition
sell_signal = rsi_5m < 80 and rsi_1m < 80

// Close buy condition
close_buy_signal = rsi_5m > 80 and rsi_1m < 80
// Close sell condition
close_sell_signal = rsi_5m < 80 and rsi_1m > 80

// Entry and exit
if buy_signal
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
if sell_signal
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)
if close_buy_signal
    strategy.close("Buy")
if close_sell_signal
    strategy.close("Sell")
```

*Edit 2:

Finally I managed to create the code with version 4 so that it does the operations as I want. However, when adding the start and end date code, I  only get it from the beginning of May. Any idea why it could be?:

```
//@version=4
strategy("LongSell", overlay=true)

startDate = timestamp("2023-01-01T00:00:00Z")
endDate = timestamp("2023-05-31T23:59:59Z")

rsiValue5m = security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", rsi(close, 1))
rsiValue1m = security(syminfo.tickerid, "1", rsi(close, 1))

buySignal = rsiValue5m > 80 and rsiValue1m > 80 and time >= startDate and time <= endDate
sellSignal = rsiValue5m < 80 and rsiValue1m < 80 and time >= startDate and time <= endDate

strategy.entry("Compra", strategy.long, when=buySignal)
strategy.entry("Venta", strategy.short, when=sellSignal)

strategy.close("Compra", when=rsiValue1m < 80)
strategy.close("Venta", when=rsiValue1m > 80)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to request data from other timeframes, you need to use the [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function.

You can pass your `rsi` calculation to the `security()` and get the MTF value of it.

```
rsi_5m = security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", rsi)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The thing is when I put that line appears this: "_1m';


13:45:09 Compiling...
13:45:09 Error at 8:0 Undeclared identifier 'rsi_1m';
13:45:09 Error at 9:0 Undeclared identifier 'rsi_1m';
13:45:09 Error at 16:0 Undeclared identifier 'long';
13:45:09 Error at 17:0 Undeclared identifier 'short'

Comment: Please edit your question and add your whole code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is in Version 5; how you call rsi and security has changed along with other built-in functions.  Try using "ta.rsi" and "request.security" instead as follows:

```
// RSI conditions
rsi_5m = ta.rsi(close, 14)
rsi_1m = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1", ta.rsi(close, 14))
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, you were right! Now it compiles perfectly!

Now I just have to check the rest of the parameters because it doesn't open and close the operations as I want ha ha